# Делаю автобег для игры, хочу имитировать нажатие клавиши вперед

Tags: python-keyboard

Делаю авто бег в игре Satisfactory, и хочу чтобы при нажатии и отпускании клавише shift игрок бежал сам пока я снова не нажму shift. использую библиотеку keyboard

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: проблема в том что я незнаю как это сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import keyboard as K
import pyautogui as pg
from pynput import keyboard
def on_press(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.f9:
        return False
#    ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
#    | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
#    Клавиша закрытия программы
    try:
        k = key.char
    except:
        k = key.name
    if key == keyboard.Key.up:#==>Клавиша вверх  
        print('Автобег включен!')
        K.press('w')
        while True:
            if K.is_pressed('w'):
                K.release('w')
                print('Автобег отключен!')
                break
#       ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
#       | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
#       Проверка на нажатие клавиши 'w', но по сути можно и не писать т.к. после нажатия 'w' K.press('w') само остановиться
listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
listener.start()
listener.join()
```